# how to add column as year-month using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create and add one column year-month as index. so how to do it ?
my dataset is contain 168 raws.

```
   23.59
   26.931
   24.740
   25.806
   24.364
   24.477
   23.901
     .
     .
```

i want dataset which is look like this:

```
 Year-Month   product
  1990-1       23.59
  1990-2       26.931  
  1990-3       24.740  
   ...          ...
  1991-1
   ...
```

how to do this please help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
In [263]: df['Y_M'] = pd.date_range(
                           start='1990-01-01', 
                           periods=len(df.index), freq='MS').strftime('%Y-%m')

In [264]: df
Out[264]:
   product      Y_M
0   23.590  1990-01
1   26.931  1990-02
2   24.740  1990-03
3   25.806  1990-04
4   24.364  1990-05
5   24.477  1990-06
6   23.901  1990-07
```

Comment: ThankYou so much.. and how to take this Y_M as index?

Comment: @Jessica do new_df=df.set_index('Y_M')